# Under Eclipse on MacOS Mavericks HTML preview at localhost stopped

Tags: html, http

I just want to preview an html page in Eclipse html editor (I've tried both Luna and Mars) on Mac OS Mavericks. While running "HTTP preview" as server, the http protocol is trying to start for a few minutes, then it brings a message - " Starting HTTP Preview at localhost" has encountered a problem, Server HTTP Preview at localhost failed to start. 
I am pretty sure that this is something connected with my mac, as the same html file with the same Eclipse works fine on a windows computer. I've googled for 2 days already, cannot find a similar problem anywhere. I've tried a few things that I thought might help, like pinging localhost to check its status, but nothing helps. If anyone has encountered this problem on mac, please help me.